# how to convert list of "vertex sequence" to a vector

Tags: r, igraph

I am using Igraph package in R and when I am accessing the list of vertices names through V(graph), I am getting the following result:

```
Vertex sequence:
 [1] "d66cp96igcdnt25brjeics9d11" "bovlonq25tmuaiak6do92v9cj0" "simj1u4714pa07p38vhstusf36" "6t6tnkoh4ftbgt787pvpmp1323"
 [5] "mf987tcmm8u8j3pdo4cts6jml3"
```

The problem that I need a vectors of these names, but this is `structure(1:20, class = "igraph.vs", env = <environment>)`

my ideas to transform it with as.vector(), as.factor did not yield a result.
Is there a way how to convert it to a vector of strings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

....
Ok, I found a way out:

`V(graph)$name` will give me a vector of names

Answer (score 3):

For a more general case, just use the `as_ids()` function.

Answer (score 0):

- Assume we have this graph g

```
graph_data <- data.frame(
    from = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 8, 9, 11, 11, 5, 11, 12, 13), 
      to = c(1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9,10, 10, 11,10, 11, 12, 13 )
)
graph_edgelist <- as.matrix(graph_data)
g <- igraph::graph_from_edgelist(graph_edgelist, directed=FALSE)
g; plot(g)
```

```
IGRAPH 53e7584 U--- 13 15 -- 
+ edges from 53e7584:
 [1]  1-- 1  2-- 3  3-- 3  4-- 5  5-- 6  6-- 7  5-- 7  8-- 9  9--10 10--11 11--11  5--10 11--11 12--12 13--13
```

- The command `V(g)` will give you

```
+ 10/10 vertices, from e4ab867:
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

- The command `as_ids(V(g))` will give you a vector of node_id

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```