# How to retrieve a selective subset from a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, type-conversion

I am performing some analysis on Twitter's data. I have a vector, containing some tweet Ids from the twitter's data set that I have. I need to retrieve the tweets based on these Ids. Here is what I'm trying:

My vector contains Ids like:

```
inf_tweets_ic
Vertex sequence:
 [1] "513674833322725376" "513688141702922240" "513722572106899456" "513698876625154048" "513699086495514624"
 [6] "513699262371094528" "513699249142251520" "513699475613687808" "513699853516279808" "513700009519644672"
[11] "513700240851886080" "513700414265765888" "513700383751823360" "513700800430739456" "513700785201229824"
```

And the twitter data set looks like:

```
tweets[1:4,c(1:3,5:7)]
            tweet_id    user_id    screen_name                             hashtags retweet retweeted
1 513657169858674688   24291371    MobilePunch                                        false     false
2 513657169745440768   59461030    OBAMA_GAMES tcot;cspj;news;teaparty;tlot;ows;p2;   false     false
3 513657165731889152   82110213 onevoicechange                                        false     false
4 513657163479515136 2654587483    NycInfidel1                        ImpeachObama;   false     false
```

I then change the tweet_id from long to factor for ease and try to retrieve the tweets in the set of inf_tweet_ic, only to get this:

```
tweets$tweet_id <- factor(tweets$tweet_id)
tweets[tweets$tweet_id %in% inf_tweets_ic,]
 [1] tweet_id             user_id              screen_name          text                 hashtags            
 [6] retweet              retweeted            location             reply_to_screen_name lang                
[11] timestamp            fav_count            rt_count            
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I have also tried converting inf_tweets_ic into numeric, so that I don't have to change tweet_id attribute into factor, but as.numeric() method sort of encodes into integer, than convert:

```
as.numeric(inf_tweets_ic)
 [1] 164 347 886 491 493 495 496 497 501 504 505 509 510 512 513 523 525 537 592 941 428 410 283 589 546 606 608 611
[29] 613 614 616 621 625 661 671 704 708 709 710 718 719 722 724 725 734 742 946 681 699
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a data.frame with `tweet_id` column and a vector with tweet IDs in a reproducible manner? It's considered a good practice to boil your problem down to a very small reproducible example.

Comment: The problem is in `tweets$tweet_id %in% inf_tweets_ic` because you have a factor on one side and a vertex sequence on the other. You have to convert `inf_tweets_ic` to a numeric vector first. I can't reproduce but this post may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977157/how-to-convert-list-of-vertex-sequence-to-a-vector

Comment: Ahh! Thanks konvas. You're right, I was extracting inf_tweets_ic from an igraph object.